# When storing in double datatype in Apache IoTDB, how to change the scientific notation displayed data to normal display?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a signal value of 493874060154044416 stored in Apache IoTDB. When storing in `float` type data, there's no error reported and the display of value is normal. However, when storing in `double` type, there's also no error reported, but the display of value becomes 4.9387406015404442E17. I know this is a scientific notation display and the value itself did not change, but I do not understand why the form of data display changed. I also tried to use the `iotdb-session` interface to query the data, and it is also in scientific notation. Anyone has an idea on why this happen, and if I still want it to be normally displayed, are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, when `double` type data is converted to `string` type data, it will become scientific method form by default if the value is too large. In Apache IoTDB, you can use `getDouble` method, which is an 8-byte `double` type in Java, and can handle the display form yourself.